# mock.Setup(...).Returns(..); Not mocking

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I am running a WCF application and need to add some unit tests. Initially I tried JustMock, free version as this is the standard for the company I am at at the moment however the free version does not `support system.linq.xml`

So, I moved over to Moq and thought that this would work, however the code block below

```
Mock<IVersionFilter> mock = new Mock<IVersionFilter>();
var message = CreateValidGetProposalListMessage();
var returnValue = XDocument.Parse(GenerateXmlString());
mock.Setup(VersionFilter => VersionFilter.ParseMessage(message)).Returns(returnValue);
```

Which should mock the result of ParseMessage(...) from this call

```
public override bool Match(Message message)
{
     var doc = ParseMessage(message);

     var getProposalList = doc.Descendants(_xmlnsa + MethodConstants.GetProposalList).FirstOrDefault();
     if (getProposalList != null)
     {
        // code ommitted
     }
     /// Test code ommitted
}

public XDocument ParseMessage(Message message)
{
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(message.ToString());
     return doc;
}

public Message CreateValidGetProposalListMessage()
{
    var p = new getProposalList
    {
        Code = "xxxx"
    };

    var message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "getProposalList xmlns=\"http://xxx\">", p);

    return message;
}
```

I cant see what I have missed and would be grateful if someone could help me progress this issue forward.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your mock being used? What's in CreateValidGetProposalListMessage()?

Comment: It's hard to say, without a [mcve]. Perhaps you're using the mock wrong, or passing in a different message, or... Can you provide something we can run, and see the issue for ourselves, please

Comment: @Lotok I have edited the question, now, but I dont see how this has an effect on the question.

Comment: I'm going to guess it's an equality issue, with the setup not being matched. Try It.IsAny<Message>() as the setup argument and see if you can get the mock to fire.

Comment: @Bizhan I need to check for 1 of three values in the test

Comment: Try to use `mock.Verify()` to check that your setup valid or not

Comment: Please show the code where you are actually using the mock, and how you are passing the mock to that code. Let us not guess what you're actually doing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen updated, but I still dont see how this has an effect on why this isnt mocking

Comment: Because if you arent using the mock object properly, it wont be using the mock and therefore wont work. See my answer. If you are already doing that, show it in your question.

Comment: `IVersionFilter` is not being used anywhere in the code. Are you trying to unit test `CreateValidGetProposalListMessage` method? this method does not have any use of `IVersionFilter`

Comment: My guess now is that you are expecting that if you create a mock for the `IVersionFilter` interface, an existing concrete object that implements this interface will automagically be mocked. That's not how things work. If your code is still using the type from which the bottom code example is coming from, the original method will still be used. Whatever code that is calling these methods must instead go through the mock object, available through `mock.Object`, which implements `IVersionFilter`.

Comment: Basically, any code that calls the method(s) in the bottom code example will have to be rewritten to be given an `IVersionFilter` object, and then you can pass the mock object to that code and it will use the mock instead of the original object. But "Hey, look over here, there's a mock object here" doesn't work.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think I understand where youre trying to get at. I am am not overly famiiar with Moq as have primarily only used justmock in the past

Answer (score 2):

The setup looks mostly ok. I suspect your problem is that setup isn't being invoked at all because of argument equality.

```
mock.Setup(VersionFilter => VersionFilter.ParseMessage(message)).Returns(returnValue);
```

This is saying that `ParseMessage` invoked with something that equals `message` will return `returnValue`. If `Message` is a class this will only work if `Message` implements it's own `Equals` method.

As mentioned in my OP comment, start with the basics. Ensure that the setup is being invoked first:

```
mock.Setup(VersionFilter => VersionFilter.ParseMessage(It.IsAny<Message>())).Returns(returnValue);
```

Once you've got that working, tune it to suit the test case. You can either implement an `Equals` method for the `Message` type (Fody would be my suggestion if you want to this), or match it another way via `It.Is<Message>(message => match conditions)`.

Comment: When trying what you suggest I still get the same result

Comment: Well if you're injecting the mock `IVersionFilter` into your SUT, there isn't much more to it. If you're not injecting the mock, that's not how it works, Moq doesn't produce shims. We're all guessing until you provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: IVersionFilter is the system under test, and there are methods\functions in here that I need to call to get mocked results out of

Comment: You don't mock the system under test, you mock its dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You have created a mock of `IVersionFilter` with this line

```
Mock<IVersionFilter> mock = new Mock<IVersionFilter>();
```

But I would expect to see a class that takes a `IVersionFilter` in its constructor. You would then do

```
 var myTestClass = new TestClass(mock.Object)
```

Then when the test class uses the functionality in `IVersionFilter` it uses the mocked one

Just to clarify, TestClass would be something like

```
public class TestClass(IVersionFilter filter)
{
     public void DoSomething()
     {
         filter.DoSomething();
     }
}
```